# Stripe - one customer - need to send invoice to multiple email addresses

Tags: stripe-payments

I see no solution or even any internet discussion for a fairly obvious problem that is sending Stripe invoice/receipt to a customer, to several email adresses at once.

Docs show single email per customer object (what is obvious and clear)
https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/object
though dashboard shows promising field as "Billing emails" - it's not even present on customer object - googling that doesn't render anything useful too.

[image]

The questions is - what if my customer wants invoices/receipts sent to multiple departments and we're stuck with single email per customer?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What payments are you expecting to send invoices to multiple recipients for? Subscription recurring payments? One-time payments? One-off invoice payments?

Comment: I'd like to include all of them. (companies might require these for taxes etc)

Comment: I've just noticed that Billing emails section can be changed "by hand" manually at stripe dashboard by clicking "Edit" visible on snippet - thus is possible manual way. As of now I'll continue by not implementing API way of doing this.

Comment: Yeah, that will work for automated invoicing (i.e. for recurring subscription payments). But not for one-off invoices or one-time payments.

Answer (score 8):

I confirmed with Stripe customer support (today, July 29, 2022) that as of right now, this is a "Dashboard only feature".

There isn't currently a way to do this via API.

Comment: Very strange. Some other features are API only.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. This really should be possible with the API.

Answer (score 6):

For those wondering how something so simple yet so obviously needed can be this difficult to do (and find online), here's a run down for the UI.

I have no idea how to do this via API unfortunately, but I'm betting it's similar to the dashboard API request which is a POST to the customer object and sets `invoicing[email_to]` for the main account email and `invoicing[email_cc]` both as arrays of emails.

Now for the UI:

Go to your Customers in the Stripe Dashboard.

Click on the customer you want to edit. Then click on Actions. Under Actions click on Edit Information.

[image: Under actions click on edit information]

Then under Billing Information uncheck the box and enter as many emails as you need.

[image]

Comment: yup that's how we've ended up adding this stuff - "please contact administrator for additional billing adres"